# Gradient of a Vector Valued function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I read somewhere, gradient vector is defined only for scalar valued functions and not for vector valued functions. When gradient of a vector is definitely defined(correct, right?), why is gradient vector of a vector valued function not defined? 
Is my understanding incorrect? Is there not a contradiction?

I would appreciate clear clarification.

Thank You.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

$\def\R{{\bf R}}$It's partly an issue of naming. The gradient is most often defined for scalar fields, but the same idea exists for vector fields - it's called the [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

Taking the gradient of a vector valued function is a perfectly sensible thing to do. You just don't usually call it the gradient.

A neat way to think about the gradient is as a higher-order function (i.e. a function whose arguments or return values are functions). Specifically, the gradient operator takes a function between two vector spaces $U$ and $V$, and returns another function which, when evaluated at a point in $U$, gives a linear map between $U$ and $V$.

---

We can look at an example to get intuition. Consider the scalar field $f:\R^2\to\R$ given by

$$f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$$

The gradient $g=\nabla f$ is the function on $\R^2$ given by

$$g(x,y) = \left(2x, 2y\right)$$

We can interpret $(2x,2y)$ as an element of the space of linear maps from $\R^2$ to $\R$. I will denote this space $L(\R^2,\R)$.

Therefore $g=\nabla f$ is a function that takes an element of $\R^2$ and returns an element of $L(\R^2,\R)$. Schematically,

$$g: \R^2 \to L(\R^2 ,\R)$$

This means that $\nabla$ should be interpreted as a higher-order function

$$\nabla : (\R^2 \to \R) \to (\R^2 \to L(\R^2, \R))$$

---

There's nothing special about $\R^2$ and $\R$ here. The construction works for any vector spaces $U$ and $V$, giving

$$\nabla : (U\to V) \to (U \to L(U,V))$$

A good reference for this way of thinking about the gradient is Spivak's book [Calculus on Manifolds](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Calculus-On-Manifolds-Michael-Spivak/dp/0805390219/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1351432069&sr=8-1).

Comment: Great answer, I think there's a huge abuse of notation occurring in machine learning and related fields these days. People seem to be using gradient, Jacobian and even partial derivative interchangeably which as we know is problematic

Answer (score 3):

Sure enough a vector valued function ${\bf f}$ can have a derivative, but this derivative does not have the "type" of a vector, unless the domain or the range of ${\bf f}$ is one-dimensional. The general setup is the following: Given a function
$${\bf f}:\quad{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^m,\qquad {\bf x}\mapsto {\bf y}={\bf f}({\bf x})$$
and a point ${\bf p}$ in the domain of ${\bf f}$ the derivative of ${\bf f}$ at ${\bf p}$ is a linear map $d{\bf f}({\bf p})=:L$ that maps the tangent space $T_{\bf p}$ to the tangent space $T_{\bf q}$, where ${\bf q}:={{\bf f}({\bf p})}$. The matrix of $L$ with respect to the standard bases is the *Jacobian* of ${\bf f}$ at ${\bf p}$ and is given by
$$\bigl[L\bigr]=\left[{\partial y_i\over\partial x_k}\right]_{1\leq i\leq m,\ 1\leq k\leq n}\ .$$
If $m=1$, i.e., if ${\bf f}$ is in a fact a scalar function, then the matrix $\bigl[L\bigr]$ has just one row (of length $n$):
$$\bigl[L\bigr]=\bigl[{\partial f\over\partial x_1} \ {\partial f\over\partial x_2}\ \ldots\ {\partial f\over\partial x_n}\bigr]_{\bf p}\ .$$
The $n$ entries of this one-row matrix can be viewed as coordinates of a vector which is then  called the *gradient* of $f$ at ${\bf p}$.