# About Gradient Definition

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-analysis

I am learning about gradient and I came across a comment from in this question: ([Gradient of a Vector Valued function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222720/gradient-of-a-vector-valued-function)) that says that we can view a gradient of a function f: R2 -> R1 as a function that maps elements from R2 to element of L(R2, R), were L is a linear application from R2 to R1, why this L(R2, R), I can't seems to comprehend it, I was always thinking that gradient of f is a function that takes R2 and returns R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing up to different views of the gradient here:

The **gradient of $f$ at a single point $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$** is a row vector $\nabla f(x)$ or, equivalently, $1 \times 2$ matrix. As a vector it just gives the direction of the steepest ascent (of $f$).  Viewed as a matrix, we can apply it to any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ to get the rate of change of $f$ in the direction of $v$. That is, $\nabla f(x)$ is a linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Intuitively, the gradient of $f$ at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is, thus, a function that takes a direction (i.e. a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$) and gives you the rate of change of $f$ in the direction of this vector (at point $x$): $\nabla f(x)\cdot v$

The **gradient of $f$** is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^{1\times 2}$ which takes a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and gives you the gradient of $f$ at that point (and, thus, a $1\times 2$-matrix $\nabla f(x)$).

Alternatively, you could also incooperate the first view into the second one and say that the gradient is a function
$$\nabla f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to L(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}), x \mapsto (\nabla f(x): \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, v \mapsto \nabla f(x)\cdot v)$$

Comment: I do not quit follow the idea of : the gradient of f at a point x∈R2 is a function that takes a direction (i.e. a vector v∈R2 ) and gives you the rate of change of f in the direction of this vector (at point x ): ∇f(x)⋅v let say f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 the gradient of that is del f = (2x, 2y) and I presume that we can define it like del f: R2->R2, am i right? cuz del f(1, 1) = (2, 2) wit is a vector of R2. I'm very confused ?

Comment: Yes, the gradient of $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is exactly the second point in my answer.
The passage you are quoting from my answer is a description of what the gradient of $f$ **at a single point** is.

Comment: cool, I get that, and what about the gradient of a single point being a linear mapping from R2 to R, it is this point i am confused about the most, cus in my mind del f(1, 1) = (2, 2) is an R2 vector that describes the direction and the rate in which f increased the most, so for where this linear mapping came from? could u give me conret example sir?

Comment: I tried to expand this first point of view a bit. But to make proper sense of it, one needs a bit of basic knowledge from linear algebra (in particular, that any matrix corresponds to a linear map and vice versa).

Comment: oh, I got it now, so basically by viewing del f(x, y) as a row vector we can apply that transformation to a vector [a column vector] from the input space to get the rate of change of f(x, y) in the direction of that vector which is a scaler, (cus [a, b] x  [c, d]t, t for transpose, is a scaler, it like a dot product of the two vectors), I get it now thank u so much.